# Debugging high CPU usage during periods of inactivity

Tags: performance, docker

I'm running WordPress within Docker containers and seeing high CPU usage (40%+) at recurring intervals for about a couple hours. This is a very simple site with very little plugins and minimal CRON jobs. Note that the high load don't relate to traffic and don't necessarily occur at times where CRON jobs are scheduled to run. We have a Varnish cache in front, so the vast majority of requests don't even hit WordPress.

[image: wordpress-high-cpu]

```
Name                            Arguments    Next Run   Recurrence
wp_scheduled_auto_draft_delete  None    2015-11-03 13:32:01 (4 hours 3 minutes) 1 day
wp_version_check                None    2015-11-03 14:28:29 (4 hours 59 minutes)    12 hours
wp_update_plugins               None    2015-11-03 14:28:29 (4 hours 59 minutes)    12 hours
wp_update_themes                None    2015-11-03 14:28:29 (4 hours 59 minutes)    12 hours
wp_scheduled_delete             None    2015-11-03 14:28:37 (4 hours 59 minutes)    1 day
wp_maybe_auto_update            None    2015-11-03 18:39:00 (9 hours 10 minutes)    12 hours
yst_ga_aggregate_data           None    2015-11-03 19:05:00 (9 hours 36 minutes)    1 day
```

Is this normal behavior and, if not, any tips on where I should start looking for information to figure out what's happening?

Comment: What type of instructure is the Docker engine on (vmware, aws, etc)? What type of file system did you opt for? Which image did you use for wordpress? How do you link into mysql? It mysql also containerized? Finally OT what are you using for monitor and graphing? those are nice graphs.